# Magento getSingleton() vs getModel() issue

Tags: php, magento, singleton

I want to loop over an array of product IDs in Magento. In the loop I am displaying some custom attributes of the products as:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
   $model = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($product['id']);
   echo '<br>' . $model->getCredits();
}
```

Problem is that if the value of `getCredits()` for the first item is `true` then all the subsequent items show `true` even if they do not have the value `true`.

But when I use `Mage::getModel()` instead of `Mage::getSingleton()`, the attribute values are displayed correct.

Can anyone please explain this difference?

Comment: Mage::getSingleton get object that already exist.

Mage::getModel is new one object.

Comment: @MagikVishal: a singleton will not only return already existing objects. It will first check whether the object exists and if not, it will create the one to be used in all further calls.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Mage::getModel() will always return a new Object for the given model:

```
/**
 * Retrieve model object
 *
 * @link    Mage_Core_Model_Config::getModelInstance
 * @param   string $modelClass
 * @param   array|object $arguments
 * @return  Mage_Core_Model_Abstract|false
 */
public static function getModel($modelClass = '', $arguments = array())
{
    return self::getConfig()->getModelInstance($modelClass, $arguments);
}
```

Mage::getSingleton() will check whether the Object of the given model already exists and return that if it does. If it doesn't exist, it will create a new object of the given model and put in registry that it already exists. Next call will not return a new object but the existing one:

```
/**
 * Retrieve model object singleton
 *
 * @param   string $modelClass
 * @param   array $arguments
 * @return  Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
 */
public static function getSingleton($modelClass='', array $arguments=array())
{
    $registryKey = '_singleton/'.$modelClass;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        self::register($registryKey, self::getModel($modelClass, $arguments));
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

In your case you always want a completely new Product object/model since every product is unique...

Comment: Doesn't the `->load(ID)` make `singleton` to load the new product ID. I think we store only the model object in registry. How does the product Id association through `load()` works?

Comment: When doing a load it fills the data of the new product. As Marius pointed out below: if you have some data set for the current product that is not present in the product you will load, this data will not be overwritten and stay the same...

Answer (score 11):

`getModel` will return a new instance of the requested model every time.
`getSingleton` will always return the same instance. It's the implementation of the Singleton design pattern for Magento.
There is also an other aspect that you have to keep in mind. The `load` method does not remove all the data you have set on the product instance. For example if you do this:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setData('some_field_that_does_not_exist', 1);
$model->load(3);
echo $model->getData('some_field_that_does_not_exist'); //this prints 1
```

This is the case for you. By using `getSingleton` the second time, you get the same product instance as the first time. And when calling `load` the value for `credits` is not overwritten because there is no such value on the newly loaded product.
*Conclusion*: Do not use `getSingleton`. Use `getModel`. Or if you want to use `getSingleton` use `$model->setData(array())` before calling `load`. This will reset all the attributes.

Answer (score 5):

First of all I would like to explain the `difference between Mage::getSingleton() and Mage::getModel() functions.`

When you call the function `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')` magento will search in the memory whether there is any object available. If not it will create a new object for `Mage_catalog_Model_product` class. In the first iteration of the foreach loop this happens. But from the second iteration when magento searches in memory for Mage_catalog_Model_product class object it will find the object which was called in the first iteration. So magento won't create any new object and instead it will call the same object which is already in the memory.

BUT,

If you use `Mage::getModel('catalog/product)` this function always creates new object of `Mage_catalog_Model_product` class in the memory whenever you called it. So in the loop this function will create one object per iteration.

Answer (score 4):

you use Singleton when you want only one instance of an object in whole application. So when you use getSingleton it always returns the same object that can have some data loaded earlier.

So in this case when the loop starts it create new object (of course only if this was not done before in some other place in magento) and loads the data for $product['id']. In next loop iteration it takes the same object with previous product id data and loads to it new $product['id'] data. This is why there can be some problems.

If you want to have two different products you must use getModel.

Comment: Why is `->load($product['id'])` not enough to load new model through singleton?

Comment: load will overwrite data. So if for example in first product there is a "sku" it will be overwritten. If there would be something that exists only in first product and not in the second one, the second one would could have the first ones value.

Comment: Wanted to accept your answer, but @KennyDs was first to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You´ll find the difference between getModel() and getSingleton() in the other answers.

But if you want to speed up your code, assuming you have a collection, do the following:

```
$products->addAttributeToSelect('credits');

foreach ($products as $product) {
   echo '<br>' . $product->getCredits();
}
```

So you don´t have to load every product, which is very time-consuming.

Comment: I guess you mean "don't have to load each _attribute_", right?

Comment: You understood the problem right, but the `$products` is not a product  collection. But its a Quotecollection.

Comment: so then you can use:

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id, 'credits');

That wont load all attributes.