# Magento updateAttributes doesn't work in own modules IndexController

Tags: php, magento, update-attributes

I have created my own module and want to call the updateAttributes Method:

`Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
        ->updateAttributes(array($product_id), array('sku','123'), 0);`

I get the following error: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeId() on a non-object in [...]/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Action.php on line 69

How can I access this method? 
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As we're updating product attributes, a traditional approach is as follows:

```
<?php
//Load the Product
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id)); //By ID
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $oldSku);//By SKU
//Update product attributes via Setters
$product->setSku($newSku);
$product->setName('New product name');
$product->setShortDescription(addslashes("short description here."));
$product->setDescription(addslashes("long description"));
//Perform Save
$product->save();
?>
```

please review the following as another reference: [Magento getSingleton() vs getModel() issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756753/magento-getsingleton-vs-getmodel-issue)

-- Update --

Double check the array syntax for the attributes being passed.

```
<?php
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
->updateAttributes(array(
$data['product_id']), 
array("sku" => $data['sku'], 'price' => $data['price']), 
$storeId);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I don't want to do it in this way because I have > 30 Attributes. That's why I like the idea to push them as array into the updateAttributes-Function.