# Variables from PHP script affecting Magento checkout

Tags: php, magento

I use the script below to set a flag when a product with a specific attribute is in the cart.
My problem is that because I use this in the checkout I belive it conflicts with the other variables/arrays in the checkout and the grand total is double what it should be.

My question is how do I pass the flag out of this script without all the other variables effecting the rest of the checkout. I have tried unset($cart); thinking this would help but with no success!

(This code is placed at the top of my checkout.phtml file)

```
<?php

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$collection->addFieldToFilter(
    array(
       array('attribute'=> 'WWHAM','eq' => '1')
    )
);

$exemptProducts = array();
$exemptProductFound = false;

foreach ($collection as $product) {
$exemptProducts[] = $product->getId();
}

// now let's check if any are in the basket
$cart = new Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart();
$cart->init();

foreach ($cart->getItems() as $item) {
    if(in_array($item->getProductId(), $exemptProducts)) {
        // to make it simple, just set a flag
        $exemptProductFound = true;
    }
}
unset($cart);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not extremely familiar with cart, but instead of

```
$cart = new Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart();
$cart->init();
```

Try

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')
```

First and foremost: You should almost never use 'new'. There's no real reason not to use `Mage::getBlah`.

Secondly, the issue may lie in your using `Mage::getModel()`, I think you need to use `Mage::getSingleton()`.

The difference is that `getModel` will always give you a new object for that model while `getSingleton` will check to see if one already exists and return that instead. This means you're getting the properties of the existing cart object, which I think is the issue. Try that and we'll go from there.

EDIT: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18757105/2124039) digs into the Magento internals to show you the difference between the two.